# Twitter API to get tweet and re-tweets count in php

Tags: twitter

Is there any API for getting twitter tweets and retweets count.
Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the twitter API docs @ http://dev.twitter.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function getTweetCount($url)
{
    $url = urlencode($url);
    $twitterEndpoint = "http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=%s";
    $fileData = file_get_contents(sprintf($twitterEndpoint, $url));
    $json = json_decode($fileData, true);
    unset($fileData); // free memory
    //print_r($json);
    return $json['count'];
}
```

Comment: May I know why do we need to free memory?

Comment: @WhateverKitchen You don't.