# get twitter tweet likes,favorites and retweets by its url twiiter api php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, twitter, twitter-oauth

Hi i am using Twitter TwitterAPIExchange(http://github.com/j7mbo/twitter-api-php) laravel 5.2.
What i want to do is to get twitter likes,favorites and retweets by its url.here is the url http://imgurl.co/760598324/1835795511

here is what i have tried

```
$settings = array(
            'oauth_access_token' => access_token,
            'oauth_access_token_secret' => access_token_secret,
            'consumer_key' => CONSUMER_KEY,
            'consumer_secret' => CONSUMER_SECRET
        );
        $encde = urlencode('http://imgurl.co/760598324/1835795511');
        $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?url=".$encde;
        $requestMethod = 'GET';

        $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
        $data =  $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
            ->performRequest();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
```

it gives me this error

```
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}
```

also if i directly pass the url without encoding then it shows the whole page data like when we open the url in the browser.

but with  facebook graph api i only have to paste the url in its facebook graph api explorer to get the data from url

i have also set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false` in TwitterAPIExchange `performRequest function`

i have also tried this solution to 
[Twitter API to get tweet and re-tweets count in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148597/twitter-api-to-get-tweet-and-re-tweets-count-in-php)
but it says

```
file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

Here is the response after solving the above error

```
{
  "statuses": [

  ],
  "search_metadata": {
    "completed_in": 0.006,
    "max_id": 715462198051602432,
    "max_id_str": "715462198051602432",
    "query": "http%3A%2F%2Fimgurl.co%2F760598324%2F1835795511",
    "refresh_url": "?since_id=715462198051602432&q=http%3A%2F%2Fimgurl.co%2F760598324%2F1835795511&include_entities=1",
    "count": 15,
    "since_id": 0,
    "since_id_str": "0"
  }
}
```

it is not giving me any data of  tweet likes,favorites and retweets

Answer (score 1):

The [error code 32](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes) in the given case means that your request is invalid (malformed).

The issue with your request is that it passes wrong data.
API endpoint [`search/tweets`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) has no `url` parameter. Furthermore there is `q` parameter which is required. Since you don't pass `q` parameter, your request is invalid.

Therefore you have to pass your data as `q` parameter.

BTW you don't need to manually url-encode data and append to the URL. `TwitterAPIExchange` has appropriate method `setGetfield` for setting `GET` parameters.

So your code should look like this:

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
$data = 'q=http://imgurl.co/760598324/1835795511';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$data = $twitter->setGetfield($data)->buildOauth($url, 'GET')
->performRequest();
```

Comment: Thanks  i have tried your solution it is not giving me error now.
but it is giving me empty data in status array i have edited my question and going to put mu response in the  question.Please kindly help me on this...

Comment: I'm afraid that you **cannot** search specific URL for presence in tweets. All parameters/settings you can apply to a search are listed here: [1](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) and [2](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets). And it seems that twitter API doesn't allow what you want.